Wpforms Please enable JavaScript in your browser to complete this form
Hola estoy haciendo una pagina web con wordpress , con semplice usando el modo sigle app page, pero al momento de poner un formulario de wpform me salen con ese error, esto pasa solo la primera vez, si recargo la pagina ya no sale el error.

He intentado precargar el formulario cuando entre a la transición así a lo mejor no me salia el error "simulando" la recarga de la pagina pero no me funciono, use este codigo:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        // Tu código para recargar los scripts de WPForms
        if (typeof wpforms !== 'undefined' && typeof wpforms.ready !== 'undefined') {
            wpforms.ready();
        }
    });
});

Hay alguna solución que no sea quitar el Single app page ?

Es obligatorio usar wpforms? Wordpress y ciertos modos no son del todo compatibles con todos los plugins, mi recomendacion es que construyas tu mismo el formulario usando ajax y lo envias con wp_mail() porque eso de andar metiendole mano a los plugins no es muy recomendable y menos con ciertos modos que suelen causar problemas

Si, tendría que ser con wpforms o un plugin ya que no tengo acceso a los archivos como tal para poder hacer el formulario como me dices
